# Genymotion Android 6.0 API 23 Problem on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, android, genymotion

Genymotion Android 6.0 API 23 Problem on Ubuntu 16.04.

I have installed Genymotion 2.6.0 and have added a virtual device with Android 6.0. I am unable to install Google Apps inside the same. It says "fails to flash the archive" all the time. 
I have downloaded and tried Gapps from 3-4 different sites too but in fail.

Try to help out soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure you have the latest version of VirtualBox installed - in case not - install it this way :

Download and register the ORACLE public key.

```
wget -q -O - https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

Add the VirtualBox repository to the sources.

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial contrib"
```

Update the software repositories :

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install VirtualBox 5.0 :

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.0
```

---

Now the main part :

- Download [**ARM Translation Installer v1.1**](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=2680937&d=1397258016) ([*mirror1*](http://filetrip.net/dl?4SUOrdcMRv)).
- Drag and drop the file into your device.

[image]

[image]

- Reboot the virtual device.
- Download the correct version of **`Google Apps for Android`** :

  - [Google Apps for Android 6.0](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=24052804347835438)
  - [Google Apps for Android 5.1](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=96042739161891406)
  - [Google Apps for Android 5.0](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=95784891001614559)
  - [Google Apps for Android 4.4.4](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=23501681358544845)
  - [Google Apps for Android 4.3](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=23060877490000124)
  - [Google Apps for Android 4.2](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=23060877490000128)
  - [Google Apps for Android 4.1](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=22979706399755082)
  - [Google Apps for Android 2.3.7](http://www.mediafire.com/download/bs063kb0m742o5l/gapps-gb-20131027-signed.zip)
- Drag and drop the correct gapps (**`gaaps-*.zip`**) file to the virtual device.

(Be patient during the file transfers.)

[image]

- Restart the device again.

You should see all **Google Services**, sign in with your Google ID and now you can use Google Play.

[image]

Comment: I am able to do upto this step. Google apps are appearing but I am unable to login via google. It says Play  Services has stopped.                                                Whats should I do to resolve it???

Comment: I retried it, Now it worked. Had some library issues also.